# Health monitoring for an ASP.NET application with ADFS authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, adfs, health-monitoring, adfs2.1

We have a an MVC4 web application that has been running basic authentication, but we are now setting it up to use ADFS.

Until now there has been a simple health monitor service that has been checking the page with username/password through an HttpWebRequest.

We have tried to continue with this approach, using DefaultNetworkCredential and following the redirected request to the token server. A second HttpWebRequest is used to handle the response from the token server. This method works when run locally, but fails when called from a web page. It also seems too cumbersome for a simple health check.

Basically, is there a good way of health-monitoring an MVC application with ADFS authorization?